# Return only arrays with values laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this array structure, I want the filtered version without the NULL array.

[image]

Comment: A few things: You should paste this as code, not an image. You should show us some attempts you've made (any array logic you've written). How should the final array look? Should the key's with NULL values be removed or should their value-pair have something/anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_filter with a call back that checks for the null values:

```
<?php
    function getNonNull($array){
        return array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
           return !(is_null($v["name"]) || is_null($v["price"]) )
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
    }
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: There's also the somewhat cleaner approach of using Laravel's built-in `filter` function on a Collection: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter